# How can I use Bootstrap's tabs and jQuery Mobile's pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site that uses Bootstrap for desktop and jQuery Mobile for mobile devices.  I am running into a problem with the HTML structure for tabs in Bootstrap vs. pages in jQuery Mobile.  Essentially the jQuery Mobile pages end up being nested if I use Bootstrap's HTML (as seen below).  When the jQuery Mobile `data-role="page"` tags are nested it does not seem to work.  Any ideas?

```html
<div class="tabbable" data-role="page"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" data-role="page">
             <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" data-role="page">
        <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used to solve this problem was a jquery mobile plugin called [subpage](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget).

I changed the nested pages to subpages and it worked.